# How can increase size of background image in Adaptive card for bot emulator?

Tags: bots, botframework, adaptive-design, adaptive-cards

> I am creating a adaptive card with background image, i want to increase the size of the background image as 400X400.

```
 AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();
    card.BackgroundImage = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg";

                        // Body content  


                        // Add text to the card.  
                        card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Hiya, I am testing Adaptice card background image. <a>https://www.google.co.in</a>",
                            Size = TextSize.Large,
                            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder
                        });
```

> I am testing with bot emulator.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this feature is not supported for now, the background image will automatically cover the `AdaptiveCard` from card's top-left-corner, it will firstly be scaled to fit the available width and in the meantime keep its original aspect ratio. And card's rendering depends on different clients, some clients limits the height of card and some doesn't. For bot emulator, it will not limit the height of card, so the card's height will increase along with the content of `AdaptiveCard`.

So, if your image for background is not high enough than card's height, it can not cover the whole and if it is higher, the down part of image will be clipped.

This is how background image works for now, there is no method to control its size in our bot.